# iCalendar (.ics) calendar item feed - ability to NAME the calendar description programatically?

Tags: icalendar

I'm creating a iCalendar (.ics) calendar items feed for a web app.

On an iPhone for instance, I can connect to the .ics feed (which works), but it requires you to manually "name" the calendar Description, otherwise it defaults to the URL.

Is there a tag I can add to my .ics code to **automatically enter the calendar Description** as the name of my app instead of the long URL? (so users don't have to manually change it)

The iCal docs are pretty long, and I haven't seen anything yet... (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer.

Add a X-WR-CALNAME tag with the name. Seems to work great!

Comment: Yeah - an unofficial extension, but seems to be accepted by most